# Selenium and 2captcha projects encountering 'g-recaptcha-response' problem

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, recaptcha, 2captcha

I have a simple program that uses Selenium to log into a website, solves the reCAPTCHA using 2captcha, and completes the login process. However, after solving the reCAPTCHA and loading it into the textarea with the 'g-recaptcha-response' ID, when I click on the login button, the website still gives me a 'Required field must not be blank' error and won't let me proceed. What could be the problem?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from solveRecaptcha import solveRecaptcha
import json

accounts = json.load(open('accounts.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8'))

options = Options()
options.binary_location = r'C:\Program Files\Firefox Developer Edition\firefox.exe'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get('link')
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'email-input').send_keys(accounts['email'])
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'password-input').send_keys(accounts['password'])
result = solveRecaptcha("sitekey", "link")
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'g-recaptcha-response'))
)
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('g-recaptcha-response').innerHTML = " + "'" + result + "'") # this line works correct with no errors, i can see the result with inspect element
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'login-btn').click() # but when i click the button, recaptcha says like "Required field must not be blank"
driver.implicitly_wait(1000)
```

this is current result: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SbtS9.png)
and the error is coming from the website, not the reCAPTCHA. I think the problem is not related to 2captcha, but more likely to be related to Selenium.

Comment: Have you able to solve this issue? Maybe there are two recaptchas as well, v2 and v3. Be careful.

Comment: Hi, I currently have the same problem. Have you solved yours?